How I can "convert" IStorage to a byte array or to an IStream?
I have implemented a drag-and-drop receiver (C++, WINAPI). It allows me to get a storage with a dragged object (OLE IStorage object). I need to "convert" it to a byte array (something like a "MemoryStream") to pass it to another program or to store in a file.
After reading MSDN, I haven't found a method that converts IStorage content to a byte array (maybe to an IStream object - it will be simple to make such conversion of a IStream).
How can I "convert" IStorage to a byte array or to IStream?
PS: in this topic I got a good advise how to save IStorage to a disk. But I doubt that making IStorage copy, saving it to disk, and reading the byte array from the disk to memory is very optimal for me.

The IStorage::OpenStream() method returns an IStream for reading data from the storage. Use  IStorage::EnumElements() to discover the available streams.

CreateStream method allows you to create a stream with the same content as the storage object. Just read bytes from that stream object and put them in your array.

@John, I had read MSDN docs about IStorage::CreateStream, but I had understood as IStorage::CreateStream creates a new stream inside my storage. Do you mean it creates an independent stream outside of my storage ?

@Remy, if I consider enumerating and opening all streams, I should scan substorages of my storage as well and it should be done recursively. Do you mean such algorithm of "converting"?

@LUN potentially, yes. You will have to check if you are actually receiving nested storages or not. IStorage is not a common format used for Drag&Drop, though.

You are probably looking for StgCreateDocfileOnILockBytes and possibly CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal. This gives you an IStorage implementation backed by an in-memory byte stream. To save your IStorage into that stream, call IStorage::CopyTo

@LUN I don't know if it is independent or not and I don't understand the distinction you are making between inside and outside. But the point is that you can read the stream to get the bytes that are inside your storage. I thought that was what you wanted.

@John, certainly, I could read a stream inside a storage. But my program receives drag-and-dropped MS Outlook letter (dragged from Outlook directly).
I get it in TYMED_ISTORAGE format. It may have complex structure - several streams, substorages with their own structures (substreams , substorages) etc.
When I asked about "converting" a storage to a stream(), I had in mind a single stream() that absorbs/encapsulates all data structures of a source storage.
So I expected to read this single stream instead of getting all storage data recursively.

@LUN Well I don't know, I'm just reading the documentation. I assumed that CreateStream would present a flat view of the data in the storage, but you obviously know more about this than me.
